# Need help in Django Templates(using forloops)

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have 3 models namely `Uses`, `Customer` and `Services`. I have a query whose result is stored in the variable `count`.

This is the query

```
counts = Services.objects.filter(uses__customer=customer).annotate(times_used=Count('uses'))
```

Each count[x].times_used has a variable,x ranges from 0 to infinity.

I have used a for loop in my html  to get all the Services which I have passed through context in views.
Now I need to get unique value of count for each service. How can I do this.

Here is my html code

```
<table class='table table-bordered' id='dataTable' width='100%' cellspacing='0'>
    <thead class='bg-primary'>
        <tr class='text-white'>
            <th>Service-Id</th>
            <th>Service-name</th>
            <th>Count</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="text-dark">
        <tr>{% for service in services %}
            <td>{{ service.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ service.service_name }}</td>
            <td>#code for printing count[x],times_used#</td>
            <td>{{ service.price }}</td>
        </tr>{% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want to get the index of a given service? Or to show another list with corresponding info by index relative to services?

Comment: I want to show another list with corresponding info by index relative to services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% for elem_1 in results_1 %}

    {{elem_1}}

    {% for elem_2 in results_2|index_filter:forloop.counter0 %}

    {{elem_2}}
       
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can use that structure in your template, anywhere.

You use a builtin filter "index_filter".

Basically, when myvar is piped with `|` to `index_filter:forloop.counter0`, then the function will call the element in results_2 with index = `forloop.counter0`. This later counter being the one of the parent for loop.